# Executable jar file is not responding and not running

Tags: jar, exe

I wanted to convert .java file to executable jar file,i did so in the command prompt. But everytime i double click (open) it nothing happens.

```
jar cf Calculate.jar Calculator.java
```

This is what i typed in the cmd. How to get an executable file? I use windows

Comment: Is the callss containing the `main`-method specified in the Manifest?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works, that way you are creating a jar archive with that .java file in it.

If you want to create the jar manually (if you want to do it one time, instead of using a build tool like ant or maven, it could have some educational value), you have to compile your .java file to a .class with `javac`, add it to the jar and then modify the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF manifest file to specify `Calculator` as value for the `Main-Class` attribute.

See this old [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) from Sun.